# Flask flask-login need to create an abstract class and subclasses

Tags: flask, flask-login

I am still learning how to use flask and flask-login, I need to create a User abstract class and then two subclasses Admin and Customer extends to User class. Can I do that with Flask and Flask-login?

Thanks,
Jo

Comment: Yes you can do that. Do you have any specific error?

Comment: Just implement your models first the way you like them. It is easy to make them work with flask_login later - it's just a matter of implementing a few methods on your user class.

Comment: I think I know what to do now. Thanks for your comments!